# Pass EF Model To View in "Create View" shows validation message for @HTML.Editfor but not for @HTML.Dropdown ? Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, validation

i have a create Actionresult method for Create view ,

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            StructureEntities db = new StructureEntities();
            ViewBag.CityId = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityId", "CityName");
            ViewBag.RegionId = new SelectList(db.Regions, "RegionId", "RegionName");
            return View(emp);
        }
```

VIEW (Create),

```
    <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TribeId, "TribeId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("TribeId", null, @Resource.SelectTribe,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TribeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Profile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.Profile)" style="margin:5px" height="80" width="80" id="profilePreview" />
                <input type="file" name="ProfileUpload" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="ShowImagePreview(this, document.getElementById('profilePreview'))" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Profile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Model (Employee) is,

```
 [Display(Name = "TribeId", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource),
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "TribeIdRequired")]
        public Nullable<int> TribeId { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource),
                  ErrorMessageResourceName = "FirstNameRequired")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

public string Profile { get; set; }

 [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase ProfileUpload { get; set; }

 public Employee()
        {
            Profile = "~/AppFiles/Images/default.png";
}
```

Now issue is that if i do not pass "Employee" to view in Action method like,

```
        return View();
```

I get Validation message for first name as well as for tribe, But if i pass model to view `return View(emp);` i do not get validation message for TribeId and while passing values for both firstname and Tribeid is `NUll`

Reason for passing model to view is i have default image profile that is populating from model until image is not selected.

How can i show validation message of tribeId by passing model to view.

Hopes for your suggestions.

Comment: TribeId is Nullable<int> therefore null is valid entry this is the reason you don't get a validation message.

Comment: I can have validation message even when it is nullable but when i do not pass employee model to view. As i pass employee to view it does not show validation message

Comment: It will either contain an integer or null, so when you pass the model to the view TribeId will always be valid.  If you it was an integer (i.e. not nullable) it would still be valid default for int is 0.  If you don't pass in the model at all that is different thing as the model it expects isn't valid/doesn't exist.  You could use the range annotation which might help you achieve the type of validation your after.

Comment: I sort it out. it is even showing validation summery on  Nullable<int>. I fixed it by deleting my Create view and recreate it from scalfolding option and redesign it than it works.  :|